# Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(opinions.tdm, 1:10, ) : subscript out of bounds R

Tags: r, text-mining, data-cleaning, text-classification, inspect

I am following the exercise on this link: 
https://data.library.virginia.edu/reading-pdf-files-into-r-for-text-mining/

In the section of Inspect:

**inspect(opinions.tdm[1:10,])**

I got this message, and I cannot follow.

**Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(articles.tdm, 1:10, ) : 
  subscript out of bounds**

Somebody can help me please!
Thanks

Comment: It's probably an out of date guide. What specifically are you trying to do with that code? It's better it you include a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question itself.

Comment: This error occurs when there are less than x terms in the opinions.tdm. In this case less than 10, because you are asking to show the first 10 (1:10) results. Use `inspect(opinions.tdm)` to see if you actually have any terms in the termDocumentMatrix.